# How to include thridparty jars in my Android APK with android-maven?

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

I am using [android-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) to manage my android project. But maven doesn't package the thirdparty jars when generating the apk. How should I configue the pom.xml?

Comment: I think is better if you can post your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example maybe can helps, on this I add `ORM-Lite` , `ABS` and `JUnit` libs:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- orm-lite dependecies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
            <version>4.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.35</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Both `ORM-Lite` libs on this `pom.xml` are jars.

Answer (score 1):

I use Fat Jar, it's a eclipse plugin could help to include jar to your apk when you export.
very easy to use.

You can find it here: 
http://fjep.sourceforge.net/